# Using a no-method trait implementation in a different module

Tags: rust

I have lib.rs:

```
pub mod genetics {
  use std;

  pub trait RandNewable {
    fn new() -> Self;
  }

  pub trait Gene : std::fmt::Debug + Copy + Clone + RandNewable {}

  #[derive(Debug, Copy, Clone)]
  pub struct TraderGene {
    cheat: bool,
  }

  impl RandNewable for TraderGene {
    fn new() -> TraderGene {
      TraderGene {
        cheat: true,
      }
    }
  }

  #[derive(Debug)]
  pub struct DNA<G: Gene> {
    genes: [G; 3],
  }

  impl <G: Gene> DNA<G> {
    pub fn create() -> DNA<G> {
      DNA {
        genes: [RandNewable::new(), RandNewable::new(), RandNewable::new()],
      }
    }

    pub fn mutate(&self) -> DNA<G> {
      let mut copy = self.genes;
      copy[0] = RandNewable::new();
      DNA {
        genes: copy,
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and I'm trying to use the definitions in main.rs:

```
extern crate trafficgame;

use trafficgame::genetics::{DNA, TraderGene, Gene, RandNewable};

fn main() {
  let t1: DNA<TraderGene> = DNA::create();
  let t2 = t1.mutate();
}
```

but I'm getting two errors:

```
the trait `trafficgame::genetics::Gene` is not implemented for the type `trafficgame::genetics::TraderGene
```

and

```
type `trafficgame::genetics::DNA<trafficgame::genetics::TraderGene>` does not implement any method in scope named `mutate`
```

`TraderGene` definitely implements the `Gene` trait, but it seems like the impl for `RandNewable` isn't in scope in main. The other problem is that since mutate isn't declared in a trait, I don't know what to import in main in order to reference mutate. Am I organizing things incorrectly?

Comment: FYI, the Rust style is 4-space indents.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Even though your `Gene` trait has no methods, `TraderGene` will not automatically implement it, even if it implements all of `Gene`'s supertraits. You must write an empty `impl` in your `genetics` module:

```rust
impl Gene for TraderGene {}
```